# AngularJS update the view when $rootScope changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to build an `angular` application that has a sidebar that updates various elements within the DOM.

Currently I have the following configuration:

`index.html`

```
<div id="sidebar" ng-controller='SidebarController' ng-class="myclass" class="col-md-2 animated fadeIn" ui-view="sidebar" ng-cloak>
        <i ng-click='toggleSidebar()' class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>
        <div class='col-md-12 main'>
            <section id='templates'>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <label class="active btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)' uib-btn-radio="'t1'">Template 1</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)' uib-btn-radio="'t2'">Template 2</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)' uib-btn-radio="'t3'">Template 3</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="templateModel" ng-click='changeTemplate(templateModel)' uib-btn-radio="'t4'">Template 4</label>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-12 other'>
            <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open" heading="Other fun things you can edit" panel-class="">
                    <section id='Option'>
                        <span>Select Option type</span>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <label ng-model="optionChoice" ng-click='optionType(optionChoice)' class="btn btn-primary" uib-btn-radio="'optiona'">Option A</label>
                            <label ng-model="optionChoice" ng-click='optionType(optionChoice)' class="active btn btn-primary" uib-btn-radio="'optionb'">Option B</label>
                            <label ng-model="optionChoice" ng-click='optionType(optionChoice)' class="btn btn-primary"  uib-btn-radio="'optionc'">Option C</label>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </uib-accordion-group>
            </uib-accordion>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="main-container" class="col-md-10 animated fadeIn" ui-view="mainContent" ng-cloak></div>
```

and the `controller` associated with it `SidebarController.js`:

```
application.controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$state', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $translate) {
    //Select Option
    $rootScope.optiona= false;
    $rootScope.optionb= true;
    $rootScope.optionc= false;
    $scope.optionType= function (optionChoice) {
        switch (optionChoice) {
        case "optiona":
            $rootScope.optiona= true;
            $rootScope.optionb= false;
            $rootScope.optionc= false;
            break;
        case "optionb":
            $rootScope.optionb= true;
            $rootScope.optiona= false;
            $rootScope.optionc= false;
            break;
        case "optionc":
            $rootScope.optionc= true;
            $rootScope.optionb= false;
            $rootScope.optiona= false;
            break;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then I have another template called `home.html`:

```
<div id='mybtn' ng-if="general.optiona" class='alt-btn btn btn-primary' role="button">Option A</div>
<div id='mybtn' ng-if="general.optionb" class='alt-btn btn btn-primary' role="button">Option B</div>
```

and the controller `MainPageController.js`:

```
    application.controller('MainPageController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$state', '$window', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $window, $translate, $location) {

        $scope.general = {
            optiona: $rootScope.optiona,
            optionb: $rootScope.optionb,
            optionc: $rootScope.optionc
        }
 }]);
```

My hope would be that the relevant div would show depending on the option selected but that is not the case. Is there a way the `MainPageController.js` will automatically update when the `SidebarController.js` updates `$rootScope`?

Also I know its not best practice to store things in the `$rootScope` but for this instance I've opted to do it.

I'm also recieving no errors in the console window. The application is running within my browser fine but I'm unable to update the interface accordingly

any help much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of putting it in `$rootScope` why not use `$localStorage` which would be hassle free.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use $rootScope, this is not what it is meant for.
please read about angular Services and use them instead to share data across different parts of youre application.

any way for youre question - if you want to detect a change in the $rootScope use the $watch function, you should read the documentations anout that also.

Good luck.